# Autheticate via Laravel Sanctum by passing token as a GET query parameter

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I know the dangers of passing the token as a GET parameter. I've seen [this](https://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#query-param) and [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-5.3). However, in my case there is no other way because the route will get called by a script which I have no influence on.

I think I should implement a custom Guard which extends the `Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard` and override the `public function user()` method. What I don't understand is, where does `$this->callback` point to? `dd` says it's an instance of `Laravel\Sanctum\Guard` .. but which method?

```
Laravel\Sanctum\Guard {#265 ▼
  #auth: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager {#267 ▶}
  #expiration: null
  #provider: null
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to let some requests with TOKEN URL to return a pdf content. So I created middleware to validate if a token exists and then add it in to the header response, in that way I took advantage of the "normal" sanctum token validation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/**
 * This middleware check if the request has _token key and adds this into the Authorization header to take advantage of
 * the sanctum middleware
 */
class CheckTokenAndAddToHeaderMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return Response|RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $all = $request->all();
        if (isset($all['_token'])) {
            Log::debug('token from http param', [$all['_token']]);
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', sprintf('%s %s', 'Bearer', $all['_token']));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Given my requirement, I decided to put this middleware over all the URLs, so I added it before all API calls (it could be different for you).

**Kernel.php**

```
/**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        
        'api' => [
            CheckTokenAndAddToHeaderMiddleware::class,
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
        ],
    ];
```

I hope this could be useful for someone.
Regards.

Comment: Very nice approach. Simple, I like it

Comment: very smart solution

Answer (score 5):

You can add the below code in AppServiceProvider boot method to authenticate using the token as query param. Laravel sanctum accepts the callable function which overrides the default. You can modify the code the way it fits for your application.

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Sanctum::getAccessTokenFromRequestUsing(
        function ($request) {
            return $request->token;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Heres my version of the middleware that will look for a token in the URL and attach it to the request as an authorization header. Does not do anything if this header is already present.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AddSanctumTokenToHeaders
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // If the URL contains a token parameter - attach it as the Authorization header
        if ($request->has('token') && !$request->headers->has('Authorization')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->token);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then register this middleware in your api route group (or any group you want this action to apply to)

```
<?php 

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AddSanctumTokenToHeaders::class,
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution now.. I ended up extending `Laravel\Sanctum\Guard` and registering a new `Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard` with the custom Sanctum Guard.

Here is the result:

app/Services/Auth/CustomSanctumGuard.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\Auth;

use Arr;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Events\TokenAuthenticated;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Guard;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use Laravel\Sanctum\TransientToken;

class CustomSanctumGuard extends Guard
{
    /**
     * Retrieve the authenticated user for the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        if ($token = $request->bearerToken() ?: $request->token) {
            $model = Sanctum::$personalAccessTokenModel;

            $accessToken = $model::findToken($token);

            if (! $this->isValidAccessToken($accessToken) ||
                ! $this->supportsTokens($accessToken->tokenable)) {
                return;
            }

            $tokenable = $accessToken->tokenable->withAccessToken(
                $accessToken
            );

            event(new TokenAuthenticated($accessToken));

            if (method_exists($accessToken->getConnection(), 'hasModifiedRecords') &&
                method_exists($accessToken->getConnection(), 'setRecordModificationState')) {
                tap($accessToken->getConnection()->hasModifiedRecords(), function ($hasModifiedRecords) use ($accessToken) {
                    $accessToken->forceFill(['last_used_at' => now()])->save();

                    $accessToken->getConnection()->setRecordModificationState($hasModifiedRecords);
                });
            } else {
                $accessToken->forceFill(['last_used_at' => now()])->save();
            }

            return $tokenable;
        }
    }
}
```

app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

use App\Services\Auth\CustomSanctumGuard;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::resolved(function ($auth) {
            $auth->extend('custom', function ($app, $name, array $config) use ($auth) {
                return new RequestGuard(
                    new CustomSanctumGuard($auth, config('sanctum.expiration'), $config['provider']),
                    request(),
                    $auth->createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null)
                );
            });
        });
    }
}
```

config/auth.php

```php
<?php

return [

    // ...

    'guards' => [
        'custom' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        // ...
    ],

    // ...

];
```

config/sanctum.php

```php
<?php

return [

    // ...

    'guard' => ['custom'],

    // ...
];
```