# How to download an inline pdf received from API using javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, download, pdf-generation

I have a backend which handles various actions with pdfs, one of them - combining multiple pdfs into a single one.

The scenario is as follows:

- User arranges multiple pdfs in a virtual list and gives this list a
  name.
- User clicks "download list" button.
- Backend (Laravel) is called over API to merge the needed pdfs and returns a
  file response. `return response()->file(realpath($pathToFile), ['Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file,'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);`

What I need to do is open this received file in a new window as inline pdf preview but I must have it named (I've tried using blobs but there's no option to provide a title) so that when user clicks on the "download" button of the pdf viewer, they get a named download, which is named by the list title. Sounds like a pretty basic task but I can't find any proper solutions on how to achieve this. Providing url to a file instead of a file response is also not an option because users are only allowed to download their lists and they should not be able to retrieve these files directly by url.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the information on this subject. I managed to solve my problem by a two-layer pdf access route. What I mean by that is first it calls a route to check if user has access to a specific file (auth token is passed by axios) if they do have access, I issue a single use token, which is then immediately used on redirect to another route, which checks the token, fetches the file and expires the token by destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue by a walkaround, which is probably not the most optimal solution and feels a bit hack-ish but that's the only solution that worked for me.

I created two routes on my API backend:

**1st route**

`Route::post('/download-file', 'PdfProcessController@downloadFileApi');`
Accepts file `id` as a parameter. `downloadFileApi` method checks if user has access to the needed file, if they do, issue a token using `Sanctum` as so `$token = Auth::user()->createToken('access_file_token');` lastly, this method returns url, which is a call to the second API route using the generated token `return sprintf('%s/api/download-file/%s?_token=%s', env('APP_URL'), $request->input('id'), $token->plainTextToken);`

**2nd route**
`Route::get('/download-file/{hash}', 'PdfProcessController@downloadFile')->middleware(['token.to.header', 'auth:sanctum']);`
The `token.to.header` middleware is implemented based on this answer [Autheticate via Laravel Sanctum by passing token as a GET query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71066214/autheticate-via-laravel-sanctum-by-passing-token-as-a-get-query-parameter)
Inside `downloadFile` token is destroyed (because it has been used) and an inline pdf is returned.

On my front-end I do

```
this.$axios.post('/api/download-file', {id: fileid})
.then(response => {
  window.open(response.data, '_blank');
})
```